# Phase difference problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, wavelength, harmonics

[image]

What's the phase difference between A and B on the following diagram. Where it is a standing wave. This question doesn't even make sense to me as from watching animations of standing waves, points A and B cannot even appear at the same time. We cannot have two minimums next to each other. So what is it asking?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It’s a standing wave because the nodes (the location of where the waves cross the axis) are fixed.  If it were a traveling wave the nodes would move as a function of time.

You can write the wave as sin(k x). Where k is a wave number and x is the 1d coordinate.   The phase difference is Pi.

Note the above isn’t complete because it doesn’t include the observation that the amplitude will change as a function of time.

Answer (score 0):

A standing wave, $s(x,t)$, is a *product* of a time periodic function with a spatial periodic function. In 1D this means $s(x,t) = f(x)(g(t)$ where $f(x+p)=f(x)$ and $g(t+T)=g(t)$, some $p$ and $T$. For example, $s(t)=A\sin(kx+\psi)\sin(\omega t +\phi)$. In the product the temporal phase and the spatial phase are not related.

This $s(t)$ could represent a pair of boundary conditions, say, fixed "walls" at $x=0$ and $x=L$ for $s(0,t)=0$ and $s(L,t)=0$ when $\sin(\psi)=0$ and $\sin(kL+\psi)=0$, from which follow $\psi=m\pi$ and $kL+\psi =m'\pi$ and $k=\frac{n\pi}{L};$ $n=m'-m$ irrespective of the temporal phase and frequency.